# VMWare - Get notified when someone is accessing via Remote-Console

Tags: vmware-esxi, virtual-machines, remote-desktop, vmware-vsphere, remote

recently i (got) moved to a virtual machine with my workstation. There's only one thing i am worry about - 40 people will have the ability to watch me working without me knowing about (except cursor is overtaken).

To avoid this i've set the param

```
RemoteDisplay.maxConnections
```

to **1**

But figured out if i connect to the vm via Windows-Remote-Desktop (mstsc) there will still be someone able to connect directly via the VMWare-Console.

Is there any other way to avoid this? Is it dumb (or even possible) to set the value down to 0?

If not - how can i get noticed about anyone's "watching" me/joinging the console?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

They cannot watch you do anything using the VMWare console, as you are connecting using RDP or similar protocol. Your session will not be shown on the VMware console.

Comment: We tested and 'he' was moving my cursor using console why i was connected via RDP

Comment: Sorry, this is not possible. Windows "locks" the console screen when you are connected with RDP. Was he connected to RDP as well and "connected" to your session using normal Terminal Services / RDS methods?